# Elasticsearch running in docker on VM - Index Crashes every hours

Tags: elasticsearch

My setup:

elasticsearch logstash and metricbeat running as containers in docker-swarm mode. Metricbeat sents its logs to logstash and is written into the elasticsearch database.

One of each parts.

The Database persists on the host with the

> --mount

parameter.

After some time (about 1h or earlyer). The index from metricbeat turns red.

and i got the log on elasticsearch:

> elastic-logstash-1.1.y03yuuhpi2fp@ucore01.solutions.test    |
> [2017-09-01T08:26:08,287][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
> retrying failed action with response code: 503
> ({"type"=>"unavailable_shards_exception",
> "reason"=>"[metricbeat-2017.09.01][0] primary shard is not active
> Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[metricbeat-2017.09.01][0]]
> containing [125] requests]"})
>
> elastic-logstash-1.1.y03yuuhpi2fp@ucore01.solutions.test    |
> [2017-09-01T08:26:08,287][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
> Retrying individual bulk actions that failed or were rejected by the
> previous bulk request. {:count=>125}

I adjusted with template that there should only be one shard without replicas, but it did not help.

I tried a configuration with three different nodes, but still the same. i even tried different combinations of shard / replica count but not effect there.

_cat/shards shows:

> metricbeat-2017.09.01           0 p STARTED    2998   1.6mb
> 10.143.14.2 tPPhaKt

Comment: Are you sure that your ES is still alive and didn't die because your Docker container lacks memory resources?

Comment: it is. i have some other indices running and they are still updated and not red.

Comment: Can you update your question with the result you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v`

Comment: @Val i restarted the setup. the storage that i use is a glusterfs over three vm. maybe the realy poor I/O from this is the Problem. Could this be possible?

Comment: Yes, that might well be. Still interested to see the result I asked for.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I tried Not to Expose the Data Directory to the host and it works Fine. I think this was some I/O Problem with the Storage behind.